# How to list recently modified pages=

Tags: 2013, search

I'd like to list the five most recently updated or added pages on the home page of a site. It should also list pages from subsites. I tried the different search webparts but I only get a list of documents. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: The problem is that you got only documents without pages?

Answer (score 2):

Have a play with the Content Query Web Part, it should still be available in SharePoint 2013. Configure it only to return items from the Pages libraries in your site collection, and set up an appropriate limit.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. But I now get two lines for each page, one with the title and one with the date. Is it possible to change this to a two column layout?

Comment: In the `Presentation` section of the web part's properties toolpane you can choose different 'Item Styles' that are available. To customise these further, you need knowledge of XSLT - there're quite a few tutorials out there if you Google for 'customising CQWP item styles'.